# Implementing ACL in Hyperledger Fabric v1.2

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, acl, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

I am trying to implement ACL in Hyperledger Fabric. I have tried my custom policy with `peer/proposal` and its working fine.

My question is What resource to use if I want to prevent `peer chaincode install`, `peer chaincode instantiate`, `peer channel create` and all the other commands.

ACL Default is given below:

```
# ACL policy for lscc's "getid" function
        lscc/ChaincodeExists: /Channel/Application/Readers


        # ACL policy for lscc's "getdepspec" function
        lscc/GetDeploymentSpec: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for lscc's "getccdata" function
        lscc/GetChaincodeData: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL Policy for lscc's "getchaincodes" function
        lscc/GetInstantiatedChaincodes: /Channel/Application/Readers


        #---Query System Chaincode (qscc) function to policy mapping for access control---#

        # ACL policy for qscc's "GetChainInfo" function
        qscc/GetChainInfo: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for qscc's "GetBlockByNumber" function
        qscc/GetBlockByNumber: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for qscc's  "GetBlockByHash" function
        qscc/GetBlockByHash: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for qscc's "GetTransactionByID" function
        qscc/GetTransactionByID: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for qscc's "GetBlockByTxID" function
        qscc/GetBlockByTxID: /Channel/Application/Readers

        #---Configuration System Chaincode (cscc) function to policy mapping for access control---#

        # ACL policy for cscc's "GetConfigBlock" function
        cscc/GetConfigBlock: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for cscc's "GetConfigTree" function
        cscc/GetConfigTree: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for cscc's "SimulateConfigTreeUpdate" function
        cscc/SimulateConfigTreeUpdate: /Channel/Application/Readers

        #---Miscellanesous peer function to policy mapping for access control---#

        # ACL policy for invoking chaincodes on peer
        peer/Propose: /Channel/CustomPolicy

        # ACL policy for chaincode to chaincode invocation
        peer/ChaincodeToChaincode: /Channel/Application/Readers

        #---Events resource to policy mapping for access control###---#

        # ACL policy for sending block events
        event/Block: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for sending filtered block events
        event/FilteredBlock: /Channel/Application/Readers
```

Is there any way to achieve this kind of functionality?

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

commands like `peer chaincode install`, `peer chaincode instantiate`, `peer channel create` are administrative tasks and only organization's admin can use them. The member/participants other than admin are not allowed to use them. The `ACL` is not written to handle such commands because these commands are only restricted to admin.

Hence, the answer is NO. You can not control these commands using ACL.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, ACLs relate to the chaincode packages for Lifecycle System Chaincode or LSCC (which is a system chaincode handling deployment, upgrade, and termination transaction for user chaincodes), Configuration System Chaincode or CSCC (a management system chaincode handling configuration requests to alter an aspect of a channel), client events, and peers (chaincode package, not CLI tool). Below is a chart displaying the resources in relation to each network component.

We can reference each resource by using the components category, and then its resource with / (slash) separating the two, for example ***event/FilteredBlock***.

We can use this to specify the requirements we must satisfy before a client can receive block information.

[image: ACL]